# How to use multithread in Unity3D for AI

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, delegates, artificial-intelligence

I'm making a Unity3D chess game with AI in it.

My game screen stuck while AI is searching for a good move.

It will take about 5~30 seconds normally for AI to think.

I know that is because my CPU resource are dedicate to calculating the AI.

but I open task manager, I found that my game is only used 50% of CPU, probably because my computer is intel core 2, and have 2 threads.

so what I'm thinking is :

Is it possible for Unity(or C#) to do the AI calculate in one thread, and hold the gameplay in another thread ?

so the the player won't see the stuck screen while AI is calculating.

I've heard Delegate or Event, but I still don't know the relation between multithread.

Comment: Your use case is perfect for multithreading (the tricky bits is Unity objects can't easily be shared amongst threads, but you can pass your AI queries and results using custom C# objects).. Just google for C# multithreading, you should be able to find a lot more than " Delegate or Event". Ask any *specific* questions here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Paul-Jan . so does it mean I can't use any of Unity API in my AI, cause they're in different threads ? so I can't use methods like GetComponent, or read any variables which class inherit from MonoBehaviour, is that right ?

Comment: Exactly, just pass those values directly to the AI thread (if there are many, write a specific object to contain them all, or use a dictionary), and when the thread is done read back the processed values in the main unity thread and assign them to the proper gameObject properties (or spawn objects, or whatever is the result of the AI processing).

Comment: I got it, but now the problem is the AI needs to do the "fake move" (or call it try / search) , and the fake move methods is written in the main gameplay code , and sure it calls unity api, it's not a simple chess game so the 'moves' contain lots of situation & various data. I can't copy it myself and just pull out all unity API usages. it's difficult to maintain in the future, too. I'll keep think about it. Thanks for your help! Paul.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create a model that represents the state of your game using classes (that you write) that do not reference the Unity API. These classes should just represent your pieces, and their positions on the board. You can then pass this model to your AI code running in a separate thread, where it can evaluate it and modify it to represent the new game state. You then write some controller code that will map the model into calls to GameObjects (the view in Unity's case).

By splitting your model from your view in this way you get all kinds of advantages, see: [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

You can use the .Net threads API to create your thread to do the AI processing and you will probably want to use a Latch to control synchronization between your game code and the AI thread. See: [NET Framework System.Threading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173178.aspx)

Comment: I see...... and I think the biggest problem for me now is how to split the AI needed data and the game code. The game play code isn't written by me.
In fact, the chessboard data is save in a GameObject array, and the function that AI use to "try" the moves isn't written by me ,too(like DoMove or DoSkill).  it's pretty impossible for me to write whole new code that do exactly the same results except View. Anyway, really appreciate your answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Unity's API is not thread safe, you have to execute them in main thread. Well you can try this package on Asset Store will help you to using threading easier. http://u3d.as/wQg You can simply use only one line of code to start a thread and execute Unity API safely.